# How To Display key and value from Json Object

Tags: ios, json, swift, iphone, nsjsonserialization

I'm using Json Object to display in tableview.I parsed Json successfully print data also. and I'm using  foreach statement to get the data into variable But the problem is I'm getting in variable the last item in json object. I want to display user to name variable to present name on it

here is my Json data

```
{
"Categories": [
    "school, class"
   ],
"Tags": [
    {
        "Value": "ashok",
        "Key": "Name"
    }, {
        "Value": "III",
        "Key": "class"
    }, {
        "Value": "A",
        "Key": "section"
    }
   ]
}
```

here is my model array

```
struct classInfo: Decodable {  
    let Categories: String
    let Tags: String
    let Value: String
    let Key: String
    var Name: String
    let class: String
}
```

here is my code

```
var ClassList = [classInfo]()

var name: String = ""
var class: String = ""
```

In JSONSerialization FUNCTION

```
do{
            let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: []) as! [String: AnyObject]
            print(json as AnyObject)

            let cat = json["Categories"] as? [String: Any]
            print(cat!)

         if let array = json["Tags"] as? [[String: Any]] {
                for obj in array {
                    if let dict = obj as? NSDictionary {
                        // Now reference the data you need using:
                        let Value = dict.value(forKey: "Value")
                        let Key = dict.value(forKey: "Key")
                        print(Value!)
                        print(Key!)

                        self.name = tag["Value"] as! String
                        print(self.name)

                        self.class = tag["Value"] as! String
                        print(self.class)
                    }
                }
            }
```

IN CELL FOR ROW FUNCTION

```
    cell.Name.text = "Name:\(name)"
    cell.class.text = "class: \(class)"
```

Comment: what is the name and class please add more info ???

Comment: i want to display class name in tableview class name in json

Comment: name variable updating the last item in json object

Comment: I do not understand you, but if you need class name you can use this` print(MyClass.self)`

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
class ModelClass{ var name:String ; var classs:String }

class ModelDataClass { static var modelData = [ModelClass]() }
```

in your viewController. - add values in models and 
in you cellForRowAt -- >

```
cell.nameTextLabel.text = ModelDataClass.modelData[indexPath.row].name
cell.classsTextLabel.text = ModelDataClass.modelData[indexPath.row].classs
```

Comment: how to diplay in tableview the json model please help me out

Answer (score 0):

heyy , try this then ,

```
class ModelClass {var name:String}
```

now create a custom tableView cell

```
class CustomTableViewCell:UITableViewCell { 
    var dataModel : ModelClass?{
           didSet{
           guard let model = dataModel else {return}
           print(model.name)
           // set label text here : ex := myLabel.text = model.name

        }
     }
   // declare all IBLayouts or create them programmatically... its your choice
```

}

in Your tableView cell (cellForRowAt ---> )
use this snippet

```
var dataModel = [ModelClass]()
dataModel = [ModelClass(name:"Rishabh"),ModelClass(name:"Adi"),ModelClass(name:"FFFf")]
```

now pass this dataModel to cellDAtaModel by using

```
let cell = tableView.deq() as! CustomTableViewCell //deq() - > to lazy to type whole lol ;P type by yourself 
cell.dataModel = dataModel[indexPath.row]
```

Comment: please help me out for this

Comment: what are you using ? showing me error / logs will help me out to clear your doubts